# Import from SQLite manager into a file

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, export

I'm using SQLite version 2.8.17 - 3.3.7 / PHP version 5.2.17
I've created a db with a few tables and want to export it into .db or .sqlite file but it gives me dump text.
I'd like to use this db in iPhone, but I'm currently stuck with app to manage sqlite databases.
Would appreciate any help.
Also I've tried sqlite manager for firefox, but its ugly:)

Please, tell me about an app to create sqlite databases and populate them with info for future use in iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with [Lita](http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlite/sqlite_detail_mac.html) for SQLite for this. Im my opinion it's a great tool with a nice GUI. You can import/export in several formats. Well, it's not free, but there is a trial.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully implemented what you're talking about by dumping the database (serverside) into an XML file, which the iPhone can pull via a simple http request, and then convert into it's own data structures. [Reading XML on the iPhone](http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=56).

Originally, I tried doing it how you're thinking, it was just too complicated and error-prone to justify.

Comment: I think it wouldn't fit for large amount of data